# Переходы в видео галерее

Tags: iframe, видео

Есть видео галерея, типа:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При клике на видео на заднем плане, происходит перемещение выбранного видео в центр. Проблема в том, что если видео вставлено средствами `<iframe>` то выбранное видео после клика по нему не перемещается, а начинает сразу проигрываться, при этом оставаясь так же на заднем плане. Возможно как то решить эту проблему?
Попробовал, вставить видео с помощью `<video>` все работает, но у меня обязательное условие вставка ссылки видео напрямую c vimeo. А тег `<video>` не понимает ссылку.

Answer (score 1):

решил проблему наложением прозрачного `<img>` поверх `<iframe>`. Следовательно клик происходит не по видео, а по изображению и действие отрабатывается.